# There is an error in the type of a mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing a node application with mongodb using mongoose ODM. I am getting an error while type referencing schemas that reside in different files.

I have following code in companyQuery.js file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Company = require('./company');
const connectionString = 'mongodb://localhost/company'

mongoose.connect(connectionString);

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Mongoose connected');
})
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', () => {
    console.log('Mongoose is disconnected');
})
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err, 'mongoose error');
})
```

which references the file company.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const companySchema = new Schema({
        name: {
    type: String, 
    required: true
},
founded: Date,
employees: Number,
active: true;
products: [String],
ceo: {
    name: String,
    age: Number
}
});
const Company = mongoose.model('Company', companySchema);
module.exports = Company;
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
/Users/ashley/salty-sardines/mongoose-3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:696
    throw new TypeError('Undefined type ' + name + ' at ' + path +
    ^

TypeError: Undefined type 'undefined' at 'active'
  Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.
    at Function.Schema.interpretAsType (/Users/ashley/salty-sardines/mongoose-3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:696:11)
    at Schema.path (/Users/ashley/salty-sardines/mongoose-3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:545:29)
    at Schema.add (/Users/ashley/salty-sardines/mongoose-3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:407:12)
    at new Schema (/Users/ashley/salty-sardines/mongoose-3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:110:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ashley/salty-sardines/mongoose-3/company.js:3:44)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ashley/salty-sardines/mongoose-3/companyQuery.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
```

The issue is replicated on three different machines from my repository, and I have re-written the code four times with the same result. If I remove `const Company = require('./company');` and combine the information onto one sheet, I can get it to work. Any help would be appreciated, as I have read through all other posts on this type of error and none have provided me with a solution.

Comment: One debugging option would be to comment out all the schema fields and uncomment one by one until you figure out which one is being problematic and then targeting your efforts on that specific field/type.

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately it didn't help, even when there was nothing in the schema at all. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you just need to replace this:

```
active: true,
```

With this:

```
active: {
  type: Boolean,
  default: true,
}
```

Comment: The error is still there, the same one, so I updated the question with your improvement to reduce any confusion.

Comment: @amfueger did you restart your app after the change? I just tried your initial schema and reproduced the error and with my fix everything's ok.

Comment: @amfueger you can use `nodemon` to automatically restart app on any file change. )